# how to find out, how many times a line touches a circle only using a vector, "v", a point on the line and the equation for the circle.

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles

Just as the title says.

Is there a way to calculate/ find out, how many times a line touches a circle (0, 1 or 2 times) solely using a vector, "v", a point on the line, "P", and the equation for the circle, "C"?

Examples of a vector "v" could be $$\vec{v}^{\,t}(-9, 7)$$

Examples of a point "P" could be $$P(-3, -4)$$

Examples of a circle equation could be $$(x-8)^2+(y+4)^2=16$$

Here is my trials and errors trying to figure this out...

step 1. Writing the circle equation $$(x-8)^2+(y+4)^2=16$$
step 2. Writing the parametric equation, using P as the point and v as the vector (direction).
[image: parametric equation]

step 3. Gather the functions of coordinates
$$x(t) = -3-9t$$ and $$y(t) = -4+7t$$

step 4. Plotting the functions of coordinates into the circle equtation.
$$(-3-9t-8)^2+(-4+7t+4)^2=16$$

step 5. Calculate and rearrange terms.
$$(-9t-11)^2+(7t)^2=16$$
$$(81t^2+198t+121)+(49t^2)=16$$
$$81t^2+198t+121+49t^2=16$$
$$279t^2+198t+121=16$$
$$279t^2+198t+121-16=16-16$$
$$279t^2+198t+105=0$$

step 6. Use the quadratic formula to calculate the discriminant
$$b^2-4ac$$
$$198^2-4*279*105$$
$$D = −77976$$

Conclusion.
Since D is negative, it does NOT touch the circle (unless we are entering the complex number universe).

PS. Anyone know how to make a vector using Latex for better reading experience?

Comment: $(7t)^2 = 49 t^2$

Comment: Silly me, stupid mistake, I quickly edit that! Thanks for the headsup :)

Comment: That should make the discriminant negative ;)

Comment: That is correct! Is it against the Guidelines if I keep this post up and accept your answer, or should I take it down again? :))

Comment: I assume you mean the vector is the line direction. Please confirm.

Comment: Ideally, you self-answer if you think that your question and answer has lasting value for future readers. If it's just a silly mistake and nobody has answered it, it's probably best to just delete it.

Comment: Write the equation of the line perpendicular to the line, through the circle center. Distance to intersection from center will tell you.

Comment: Is there a way to "hide" this post. What if I like to make it private only for me to see?

Comment: @Moti Yes, it is a line direction.

Comment: Calculate angle based on dot product and use sine to calculate distance. Compare to radius.

Comment: @Moti I have not quite learned that method with the sine. Anyway you can link me someone to read further onto it?

Comment: Are you familiar with DOT product?  You could learn here about it - https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/dot-product-calculator.php (use z=0 for your 2D case). Calculate distance from P to circle center. Use the tangent function to calculate the distance of the circle center from the line. Compare to radius.

Comment: @Moti Thank you so much, I will give that a look!

Comment: @NemanjaVuksanovic: Yes if you "delete" it then you can still see it at this URL.